# REST API for Artifact Latest Version Search Based on Properties

Tags: artifactory

I'm new to the REST API and need help to perform a Artifact Latest Version Search Based on Properties -> http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonProperties.

Using example `"/api/versions/_any/a/b?os=win&license=GPL"`, the request I made is `../api/versions/{repo}/_any?INT_PASS=true`

I get the following error:

```
{ 
  "errors" : [ { 
    "status" : 500, 
    "message" : "For permissions reasons AQL demands the following fields: repo, path and name." 
  } ] 
}
```

any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There was a [bug](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-7228) in this specific query and it was fixed in Artifactory version 3.5.3.